# how to search a listview items (generated from an api) using a serach textfield by typing a name/id depending on the list items needed to be found?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, search, filter

i have a list generated from an api, and i want to be able to filter it using a serach bar

for example i only want to display the employe  'salim' when i type his name

here's my code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:p1/ConfigFile.dart';
import 'package:p1/Details.dart';
import 'package:p1/add_emp.dart';


class EmpData extends StatefulWidget {
  final String token;
  DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  EmpData({required this.token});

  @override
  _EmpDataState createState() => _EmpDataState();
}

class _EmpDataState extends State<EmpData> {
  int currentPage = 1;
  List empList = [];
  ConfigFile confObj = new ConfigFile();

  //todo: get the data in a list of Strings
  Future<List> getEmpData(String token,) async {
String ip = await confObj.readIp();
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://$ip/personnel/api/employees/?page_=$currentPage" ),
    headers:{
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "JWT "+token,
    });
final String t = response.body;
var jsonData =jsonDecode(t)['data'];
return jsonData;
}

final TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();

Future<String> getIp() async{
  String ip = await confObj.readIp();
  return ip;
}



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Employees List"),
        centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        //todo: chearch field
        TextField(
          controller: editingController,
          onChanged: changed,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Search",
              hintText: "Search",
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
        ),
        
        FutureBuilder<List>(
            future: getEmpData(widget.token),
            builder: (ctx,ss){
              if(ss.hasData){
                empList = ss.data!;
                return Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: empList==null?0:empList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (ctx,i){
                      return ListTile(
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=>Details(
                                token: widget.token,
                                emp: empList[i]['emp_code'],
                                first_name: empList[i]['first_name'],
                                last_name: empList[i]['last_name'],
                                photo: empList[i]['photo'],
                                )
                              ));
                        },
                           leading: SizedBox(
                              
                             //todo: get the emp photo from the database using the conf ip adress
                             child: FutureBuilder(
                               future: getIp(),
                               builder: (ctx,ss){
                                 if(ss.hasData){
                                   return SizedBox(child: Image.network("http://${ss.data}/${empList[i]['photo']}", width: 50,height: 50,));
                                 }else{
                                   return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                 }
                               },
                             ),
                           ),
                          subtitle: Text("id: #${empList[i]['emp_code']}"),
                          title: Text("${empList[i]['first_name']}  ${empList[i]['last_name']}"),
                      );
                    }
                ));
              }else{
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            }
        )

      ],
    )
);



}
```

this is where i was going to put the search function which was called by TextField onchanged

```
//todo: this is searching function
void changed(String Query) {

 }
}
```

this is how the page looks like
[homePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyvcl.png)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to trigger a filter on your list upon the user typing on the textfield out of al the returned values from your API, or you could, upon the user typing, also grab the values and perform a call against the API with that value, but it will make it very chatty and make too make requests (one per keystroke).

Comment: how do i make a filter after getting all the data from an api ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be using a **ValueNotifier** with a **ValueListenableBuilder** if you only want to listen to a single value being changed (the search bar field) and you want to have the List render only the found values based on your match. Check out this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/ac1eb567076588e60944b15407a1ecc3) that I did based on some of your code.

Pretty much we load all data upfront, and using your **changed** event handler attached to the textfield's **onChanged**, we capture every keystroke and filter out the list based on only the matched **first_name** (you could add the last name or any other criteria). Then we trigger the **ValueNotifier** **empName** to trigger the updated list with the filtered results.

This is the simplest approach you could go for. Other approaches would be using a simple state management solution like a **Provider** and using **ChangeNotifiers** as well as **Consumer** widgets, which follow pretty much the same idea as above, but more robust and durable.

It should look like the GIF below once you put it all together:

[image]

Hope that works out for your purposes.

Comment: hello, thank you for your help, i got a problem that whenever i type anything in the search bar i got an empty list and when i delete everything the previous list return normal, so i tried to print(listViewList) and it became empty after i search anything
here's what i get without searching anything :

Comment: Edit: i posted a screenshot in your git link

Comment: i guess i know the problem, i must put the full (first_name) to work, is it possible to filter the result for example when i type (s) i get all names starting with (s) then (sa) => all names starting with (sa) and so on until i put the whole (first_name) ??

Comment: i used  filteredList = empList.where((e) => e['first_name'].toString().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())).toList(); 
and i think it works,
the only thing left is to search in both first_name  last_name or emp_code

Comment: Yeah just continue adding the other cases within the **where** clause using **and** / **or** accordingly. You almost got it! Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: it works when i used ( || ) but only searching last_name/first_name separately and doesn't give result when typing the full name or when just adding sapce

Comment: That won't work because your fields are separate. If you want to do what you're saying then you're gonna have to tokenize the search input (i.e. grab the text in the search field, split it by space, then grab each token and check for the occurrences of those tokens in each of the fields).

Comment: ok thank you, i will leave like it is instead of splitting it